# JSON format error thrown by cUrl but not Wget?

Tags: json, windows, curl, wget

I am sending a POST request via a batch script on Windows. I have manually installed wget and all works fine, but I'd like to use cUrl as it recently became a Windows 10 standard feature and can be run on other newer computers. The problem is that cUrl throws a Json formatting error despite not seeming to have any special character exceptions.

I've tried changing quotations to apostrophes and vice versa, and using backslashes and carets as escape characters. This wget script works:

```
wget --quiet ^
  --method POST ^
  --header 'content-type: application/json' ^
  --body-data '{"method":"passthrough", "params": {"deviceId": "[MyId]", "requestData": "{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}" }}' ^
  --output-document ^
  - 'https://eu-wap.tplinkcloud.com/?token=[MyToken]'
```

However the exact same JSON in cUrl is refused:

```
curl -X POST -H 'content-type:application/json' -d '{"method":"passthrough","params":{"deviceId":"[MyId]","requestData":"{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":0}}}"}}' https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=[MyToken]
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I think that your both request bodies are the same. But there is one difference thing. In your wget command, you use ``https://eu-wap.tplinkcloud.com/?token=[MyToken]`` as the endpoint. But in your curl command, you use ``https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=[MyToken]``. How about this? Because I thought that this might be a mis-writing, I post this as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistype. With the same URL the error persists. The server is returning the error, so I'm guessing that cUrl changes its formatting or content somehow?

Comment: I'm sorry. I had forgot that you are using curl for Windows 10. I posted the modified curl command as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't work, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using the curl (`C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe`) at Windows 10 on the command line for Windows.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified curl command for Windows:

```
curl -H "content-type:application/json" -d "{\"method\":\"passthrough\",\"params\":{\"deviceId\":\"[MyId]\",\"requestData\":\"{\\\"system\\\":{\\\"set_relay_state\\\":{\\\"state\\\":0}}}\"}}" https://eu-wap.tplinkcloud.com/?token=[MyToken]
```

- At Windows command line, please use the double quotes instead of the single quotes.
- At JSON object, please escape each double quotes.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about the correct URL from your reply. So please use the correct URL when you test above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it might be an escape character, but I used apostrophes around my wget command and it worked, so I thought that they would work here.

Comment: @Auspexis I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Curl on windows and kept getting JSON Error,
I switched the  single and double quotes and it worked fine

```
curl  -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer <token>" -d "{'fileid':'<fileid>','printerid':'<printerid>','type':'pdf'}" "https://printapi.ezeep.com/sfapi/Print"
```